# Use the Polkadot identicon styles for Parachains

Tags: polkadot-js, ui

the identicon style on Parachains is not aligned with Polkadot, as you can see as below.

[image]

How can parachain team make the same style or override the default settings?

According to the Polkdaot.js/UI settings: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-ui/blob/master/src/Identicon.jsx#L48,  parachains should be able to override it to `polkadot` style.

But the code here: https://github.com/polkadot-js/common/blob/master/packages/networks/src/defaults/icons.ts seems does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Polkadot.js App reads the value from two parts: ui-settings and from an *IdentityNode list*

https://github.com/polkadot-js/apps/blob/51835328db5f0eb90a9efcc7bf5510704a7ab279/packages/react-components/src/IdentityIcon/index.tsx#L29

ui-settings: the user can pick their preferred icon theme. This will apply to all networks.

And for IdentityNode list, you could do a pull request to add your node name and your preferred icon theme

https://github.com/polkadot-js/apps/blob/51835328db5f0eb90a9efcc7bf5510704a7ab279/packages/apps-config/src/ui/identityIcons/index.ts#L7

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add the identity pallet to your parachain runtime.

https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/tree/master/frame/identity